# Is it possible to reparent the high charts legend?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using the high charts library, and want to move the legend entry off the chart and into another container in the side bar.

Anyone know if this is possible?

I tried this, but the styles are all over the place:

```
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: { .... 
     events: {
        load: function (event) {
            $(".highcharts-legend").appendTo("#legendContainer");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legend is drawn using SVG.  Instead of re-parenting to a `div` reparent to a `svg` element.

```
<svg id="legendContainer" class="highcharts-container"></svg>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5AdJ/).

**EDITS**

Recent versions of Highcharts position the legend using an SVG `transform`, you might have to remove this to get the reparent to work correctly.  Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5AdJ/21/).

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work for me. Using Chromium 36.0.1985.125 Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @omikron, yes, it breaks with recent `Highcharts` changes, see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5AdJ/13/

Comment: This is awesome - just one bug I can't seem to iron out. As soon as the window is resized or moved, the legend 'disappears'... Hopefully there's a solution to this.